# Change mouse position after click

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
public class FoodToFoodGroup {  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='engage-create']//ul[@title='Message']/li")).click();
Thread.sleep(9000); 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); WebElement element = wait.until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("img#accordionIcon.accordionIcon.sprite"))); 
element.click(); }
```

I am able to click on Message Icon as shown in picture , but after the mouse is still pointing in to frame or frame is not disappearing itself. So I cannot able to click on other element.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uadEm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you hover the mouse to a different element temporary until that frame disappear. Use this method if you want to hover to a specific element

```
public static void hoverToWebelement(WebElement HovertoWebElement) throws InterruptedException {
    //log.info("Hovering over an element");
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(HovertoWebElement).perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```